# mixed effects model when within group variance cannot be estimated

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, modeling

What is a mixed effects model when the within group variance cannot be estimated.

For example I have an outcome that is very rare to begin with. Less than 5% of children have this outcome. Then I have different groups across the country who have contributed data for this condition including the covariates.

```
Binary outcome. (Good Development, Bad or Below development)

x1: Mother Tobacco (Yes/No)

x2: Mother Education   (Graduated HighSchool, Did not graduate HighSchool)

Group : State (CA, GA, NY, MD, WI)
```

This is the distribution of the outcome within each x and group

```
                     1=Good Development, 0=Bad or Below development
  CA Yes HighSchool   10                  6
      No HighSchool   67                  3
  CA Yes HighSchool   105                 16
      No HighSchool   121                 4
  CA Yes HighSchool   22                  4
      No HighSchool   126                 4
  CA Yes HighSchool   18                  5
      No HighSchool   26                  4
  CA Yes HighSchool   150                 9
      No HighSchool   66                  3



                1=Good Development, 0=Bad or Below development
  CA Yes Tobacco   74                  7
      No Tobacco    3                  2
  GA Yes Tobacco  209                  17
      No Tobacco   17                  3
  NY Yes Tobacco  140                  8
      No Tobacco    8                  0
  MD Yes Tobacco   42                  2
      No Tobacco    9                  0
  WI Yes Tobacco  208                  8
      No Tobacco   12                  0
```

The mixed effects model fails to converge. I suspect this is because sparse values in some cells for some combination of `Y+x+(1|Group)` . I am wondering if I am better off just doing fixed effects instead of random effects. I don't see any advantage in fitting mixed effects model. Kindly pardon my ignorance. Seeing your advise. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried fitting your model by direct maximum likelihood instead of REML?

Comment: @AdamO, nope, I have not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a generalized estimating question instead. They are far more likely to converge because the fixed effects are estimated in a marginal, weighted model. The interpretation, of course, is completely different, but you have already mentioned fitting a fixed effects model.

The analogous GEE model to a mixed model with a random intercept `+(1|Group)` would specify an "ID" to be the Group variable, and the correlation structure is "exchangeable". It is not identical, and the estimates will be slightly different, but the interpretation is at least tractable and highly likely to converge.